# Sed replacing only part of a longer match with a shorter replacement:

Tags: regex, bash, shell, replace, sed

So I'm measuring the total time elapsed of c program. By doing so I have been running this shell script that uses sed to replace the value of a constant (below: N) defined somewhere in the middle of a line in my c program.

```
#define N 10 // This constant will be incremented by shell program
```

Before you tell me that I should be using a variable and timing the function that uses it, I have to time the whole execution of the program externally on a single run (meaning no reassignment of N).

I've been using the following in a shell script to help out:

```
tmp=$(sed "11s/[0-9][0-9]*/$INCREMENTINGVAR/" myprogram.c); printf "%s" "$tmp" > myprogram.c
```

That replaces a 3 digit number with whatever my INCREMENTINGVAR (replacement) is. However, this doesn't seem to work properly for me when the replacement is 2 digits long. Sed replaces only the first two characters and leaves the the previous 3rd digit from the previous run without deleting it.

```
TESTS=0
while [ $TESTS -lt 3 ]
do
    echo "This is test: $TESTS"
    INCREMENTINGVAR=10

    while [ "$INCREMENTINGVAR" -lt 10 ] 
    do
        tmp=$(sed "11s/[0-9][0-9]*/$INCREMENTINGVAR/" myprogram.c); printf "%s" "$tmp" > myprogram.c
        rm -f myprog.c.bak
        echo "$INCREMENTINGVAR"
        gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram.out; ./myprogram.out
        INCREMENTINGVAR=$((INCREMENTINGVAR+5))
    done
    TESTS=$((TESTS+1))
done
```

Is there something I should do instead?

edit: Added whole shell script; Changed pattern for sed.

Comment: You can use the `-i` option to write the output back into the original file, so you don't need the variable.

Comment: Your code only replaces when there are 3 digits. Your input file has only 2 digits. So it shouldn't be replacing anything. I don't understand when you say that it leaves the previous 3rd digit, since there wasn't a 3rd digit.

Comment: And if you have a 4 digit number, it will replace the first 3, but leave the 4th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply want to replace whatever digit string is on line 11 with the new value?  If so, you'd write:

```
sed -e "11s/[0-9][0-9]*/$INCREMENTINGVAR/"
```

That looks for a sequence of one or more digits, and replaces it by the current value in `$INCREMENTINGVAR`.  This will rollover from 9 to 10, and from 99 to 100, and from 999 to 1000, etc.  Indeed, there's nothing to stop you jumping from 1 to 987,654 if that's what you want to do.

With the GNU and BSD (Mac OS X) versions of `sed`, you could overwrite the file automatically.  The portable way (meaning, works the same with both GNU and BSD variants of `sed`), is:

```
sed -i.bak -e "11s/[0-9][0-9]*/$INCREMENTINGVAR/" myprog.c
rm -f myprog.c.bak
```

This creates a backup file (and removes it).  The problem is that GNU sed requires just `-i` and BSD `sed` requires `-i ''` (two arguments) to do an in situ change without a backup.  You can decide that portability is not relevant.

---

Note that using line number to identify what must be changed is delicate; trivial changes (a new header, more commentary) could change the line number.  It would probably be better to use a context search:

```
sed -i.bak -e "/^#define N [0-9]/ s/[0-9][0-9]*/$INCREMENTINGVAR/" myprog.c
rm -f myprog.c.bak
```

This assumes spaces between `define` and `N` and the number.  If you might have blanks or tabs in it, then you might write:

```
sed -i.bak -e "/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]\{1,\}N[[:space:]]*\{1,\}[0-9]/ s/[0-9][0-9]*/$INCREMENTINGVAR/" myprog.c
rm -f myprog.c.bak
```

That looks for optional leading white space before the `#`, optional white space between the `#` and the `define`, mandatory white space (at least one, possibly many) between `define` and `N`, and mandatory white space again between `N` and the first digit of the number.  But probably your input isn't that sloppy and a simpler search pattern (like the first option) is sufficient to meet your needs.  You could also write code to normalize eccentrically formatted `#define` lines into a canonical representation — but again, you most probably don't need to.

If you have somewhere else in the same file that contains something like this:

```
#undef N
#define N 100000
```

you would have to worry about the pattern matching this line too.  However, few files do that; it isn't likely to be a problem in practice (and if it is, the code in general probably has more problems than can be dealt with here).   One possibility would be to limit the range to the first 30 lines, assuming the first `#define N 123` is somewhere in that range and the second is not.

```
sed -i.bak -e "1,30 { /^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]\{1,\}N[[:space:]]*\{1,\}[0-9]/ s/[0-9][0-9]*/$INCREMENTINGVAR/; }" myprog.c
rm -f myprog.c.bak
```

There are multiple other tricks that could be pulled to limit the damage, with varying degrees of verbosity.  For example:

```
sed -i.bak -e "1,/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]\{1,\}N[[:space:]]*\{1,\}[0-9]\{1,\}/ \
                s/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]\{1,\}N[[:space:]]*\{1,\}[0-9]\{1,\}/#define N $INCREMENTINGVAR/; }" myprog.c
rm -f myprog.c.bak
```

Working with regexes is generally a judgement call between specificity and verbosity — you can make things incredibly safe but incredibly difficult to read, or you can run a small risk that your more readable code will match something unintended.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I remember using this solution. However, I was never able to get the file to be overwritten, therefore, my c compiler compiled nothing new after the first time. That's why I have long and inefficient code above. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There are systems where the native `sed` doesn't support either variant of `-i`, so the 'edit to temporary and rename afterwards' approach is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I hope others will read your answer and fix their similar problems. 